# Selling a product using a hardware with replaced software

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, software, ownership, hardware

I bought an unbranded China-made Wi-fi router and I replaced the built-in firmware/software with another firmware/software and make it as a portable computer with my own software installed in it. In other words, I optimize and turn the hardware of being a Wi-fi router to become a small and portable computer with my software. I plan to sell it. Am I violating any legal rights or property rights to the company who sell the Wi-Fi router?

Comment: Cannot say based on the small amount of information you have provided.  At lot depends on any licenses associated with the product as your purchased it.

Comment: The built-in firmware/software used in this Wi-Fi router is an open-source Linux operating system and it's license is GPL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License)

Comment: I'm asking about the "product" not its individual components.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks for pointing out. Had some hard time looking for labeled copyright notices and registered trademark from the user manual and the carton package. I even don't see the company name selling this product.

Comment: This asks what the law does or does not permit. it is not asking for specific legal advie, nd should not be closed on that basis.